# c# Rdlc report with select query

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am having a issue with my data source in rdlc report.  So I have added the source (access database table).  In the screen to connect to this database, I added a select statement as I needed to get 2 field from a different table and clicked on 'execute query' to see results of the select query.  The issue I am having is on the report expression where I am trying to get data from this field (supmain.date_l_p and supmain.l_s_flag), it doesn't print anything except #ERROR on the report.

My select statement below:

```
SELECT transaction.*, supmain.date_l_p, supmain.l_s_flag 
FROM TRANSACTION 
   left join supmain on supmain.polnum = transaction.polnum`
```

my expression for report:

```
=IIf (Fields!Ch_Date.Value>=Fields!date_l_p.Value,"FINAL","")
```

Any ideas why this select statement is not working in the expression?

I tried to change the expression to display a field from other table and it displays correctly.

Comment: Why the period "." after transaction in the select statement ?